# Is there a more pythonic way to do this dictionary iteration?

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views

I have a dictionary in the view layer, that I am passing to my templates. The dictionary values are (mostly) lists, although a few scalars also reside in the dictionary. The lists if present are initialized to None.

The None values are being printed as 'None' in the template, so I wrote this little function to clean out the Nones before passing the dictionary of lists to the template. Since I am new to Python, I am wondering if there could be a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
# Clean the table up and turn Nones into ''

for k, v in table.items():
#debug_str = 'key: %s, value: %s' % (k,v)
#logging.debug(debug_str)

try:
    for i, val in enumerate(v):
        if val == None: v[i] = ''

except TypeError:
    continue;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `collections.defaultdict`?

Comment: Because I'm a newbie? What are the benefits of using collections.defaultdict?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at `defaultdict` within collections?  You'd have a dictionary formed via

```
defaultdict(list)
```

which initializes an empty list when a key is queried and that key does not exist.

Comment: From the example, it appears that OP has `None` values in a list in the dictionary that he's trying to get rid of, so this won't work on two counts.

Comment: @user470379.  The `None` values in the dictionary may be an simple error based on failing to use `defaultdict` in the first place.  Solving the problem -- as asked -- isn't always the best.  Preventing the problem (as asked above) is often better than "solving" it.

Comment: @user470379 I think it reads that there are `None` values in the dictionary when there is no list.

Comment: If the OP wants something other than an empty list, there's always `defaultdict(lambda:<desired default value>)` where `<desired default value>` can be almost anything desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in table.items() if v is not None)
```

or in Python 2.7+, use the dictionary comprehension syntax:

```
filtered_dict = {k: v for k, v in table.items() if v is not None}
```